# How RSA algorithm encrypt and decrypt string text?

Tags: security

I need the algorithm about encrypt and decrypt using RSA algorithm. Now I have public key, private key, and string text. The questions are

1. I need to know how to encrypt it. Encrypt each character in text or encrypt whole text.
2. How to decrypt it when ciphertext has only number. How to divide number to decrypt.

p.s. Sorry about my bad English. = ="

Comment: Did you try looking at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) and [this](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/rsa_alg.html) ? There are plenty of good info here. Also, what language are you using to do so ? []'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way is:

1. Generate a key of symmetric algorithm (for example, AES).
2. Encrypt the text with them.
3. Encrypt this key with RSA using, for example, PKCS#1 notation.
4. Compose an output structure containing ciphertext, encrypted key and other service information (symmetric algorithm identifier, recipient ID, etc.). Most used format is noted in [RFC 5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652).

Answer (score -1):

You can take each character from the string take it ascii value encrpyt it and then again convert it into text and store.do it for all characters.This will be your encrypted text.Like wise do it for decryption..
hope it helps